# making a views grid go from right to left?

Tags: 7, views

I have views, that I need placed differently. normally the images in a grid view show from left to right, but I need them the other way. How can i set a grid to show starting from right to left instead of left to right?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there are no settings in views to change this behaviour. However you can change the view format to "Unformatted" and give the .views-row a width and float:right (tweak as desired). This will line them up as a grid rtl.

Comment: Views' grid style simply prints all the rows in table cells one after the other, either right to left, or top to bottom, so yes, doing the above (using unformatted) would not only let you go in that order, it would technically be more 'semantic' html.